# distance points 3D

Tags: matlab, distance

I have a vector of points in a 3D space.

```
A = rand(80,3)
```

I want a vector containing all the distances between the points.

`D = pdist(A,'euclidean')` returns a vector 1-by-3160 
could you please tell me if it is the right function to use? 
thanks

Comment: Only one way to find out: Try it.

Comment: yes, but I don't know if it's correct...

Comment: Edit the question with the answer of whether or not "it worked".  Then we will let you know if it did the job.

Comment: How do you not know if it is correct? How about trying that function with less points where you can check by hand what's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have the statistics toolbox, it is not the correct function to use. If you do - then it is one of many functions you could use. You can also do something like:

```
sz = size(A);
A1 = reshape(A, [1 sz]);
A2 = permute(A1, [2 1 3]);
D = sqrt(sum(bsxfun(@minus, A1, A2).^2,3));
```

This calculates the distance between any two points explicitly (thus, does twice as much work, and takes over twice as much space: 6400 instead of 3180 elements). However, it's easier to look up the distance between any two points.

You can then compare the result of this calculation with the one you get from `pdist`, and convince yourself whether it's the same. Be careful - `pdist` returns a vector by default, so you need to look at the documentation to make sure you understand how to interpret it. The function `squareform` can help you:

```
difference = sum(abs(squareform(D)) - pdist(A, 'euclidean'));
```

It depends on what you want... and what your definition of "the right function" is...

Comment: thanks a lot! that was the answer that I was looking for!

Comment: If this is the answer you were looking for then please mark it as "accepted".